# Android Fragment view is null in viewpager on app resume in certain situations

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am currently developing an Android application that uses a view pager with Fragments for pages to layout out the main activity in tabs. Most of the time this works just fine for us but we are currently encounter an issues where in some cases the Fragment view is blank when the applications resumes/is created. This seems to occur only  when the app is resumed by being called by with an activity intent or by clicking on a notification while the application is in the background. This issue occurs only when the app is already loaded in the background, if the action makes the activity launch and create everything new then the issue does not occur.

The following is the code that setups our view pager.

The Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportFragmentManager().enableDebugLogging(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mainViewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this));

    // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
    tabs.setUnderlineHeight(4);
}
```

The Pager Adapter

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

Context context;

public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.context = context;
}

// Returns the fragment to display for that page
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return MainPagerEnum.values()[position].getFragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return MainPagerEnum.values().length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    MainPagerEnum mainPagerEnum = MainPagerEnum.values()[position];
    return context.getString(mainPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

The Page Enum

```
public enum MainPagerEnum {

  YOURACCOUNT(R.string.your_account, AccountFragment.newInstance()),
  LOCATIONS(R.string.locations, LocationsFragment.newInstance()),
  OCCURANCES(R.string.occurances, OccurancesFragment.newInstance());

  private int titleResId;
  private Fragment fragment;

  MainPagerEnum(int titleResId, Fragment fragment) {
      this.titleResId = titleResId;
      this.fragment = fragment;
  }

  public int getTitleResId() {
      return this.titleResId;
  }

  public Fragment getFragment() {
      return this.fragment;
  }
```

One of the Fragments that ends up with a null view

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "AccountFragment";

public AccountFragment() {

}


public static AccountFragment newInstance() {
    AccountFragment fragment = new AccountFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    LinearLayout signInLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_block);
    LinearLayout signedInLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.signed_in_block);
    TextView welcomeFamily = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.welcome_family);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.account_fetch_progress);
    Button login = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    if(AccountProperties.getActiveAccount() != null) {
        AccountFragmentUtil.showHideAccountElements(signInLayout, signedInLayout, welcomeFamily, progressBar, login, getContext());
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Using the debug logging on the fragment manager I've determined that the issues has something to do with the backstack. If the app is put into the background and the user resumes the app by clicking on it from their previous apps switcher there is no issues and the log looks like the following.

> 08-29 09:03:42.566 29172-29205/com.app D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>   08-29 09:03:45.805 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: movefrom RESUMED: LocationsFragment{5455ec1 #0 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:03:45.805 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: movefrom RESUMED: AccountFragment{9913fcb #1 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:03:46.068 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: Saved state of LocationsFragment{5455ec1 #0 id=0x7f0d00a1}: Bundle[{android:user_visible_hint=false, android:view_state={2131558528=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558554=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558605=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558606=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558607=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558608=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138}}]
>   08-29 09:03:46.068 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: Saved state of AccountFragment{9913fcb #1 id=0x7f0d00a1}: Bundle[{android:view_state={2131558571=android.widget.ProgressBar$SavedState@b04e511, 2131558572=HorizontalScrollView.SavedState{b06e676 scrollPosition=0}, 2131558573=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558574=TextView.SavedState{16c4477 start=0 end=0}, 2131558575=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558577=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558578=TextView.SavedState{2ff98e4 start=0 end=0}, 2131558579=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558580=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558581=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558582=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558583=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558584=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558585=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558586=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558587=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558588=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558589=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558590=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558591=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138, 2131558592=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@af5a138}}]
>   08-29 09:03:46.068 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: saveAllState: adding fragment #0: AccountFragment{9913fcb #1 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:03:46.068 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: saveAllState: adding fragment #1: LocationsFragment{5455ec1 #0 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:03:46.077 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: movefrom STARTED: LocationsFragment{5455ec1 #0 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:03:46.077 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: movefrom STARTED: AccountFragment{9913fcb #1 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:03:46.082 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: movefrom STOPPED: LocationsFragment{5455ec1 #0 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:03:46.082 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: movefrom STOPPED: AccountFragment{9913fcb #1 id=0x7f0d00a1}

However if the app is already in the background and something like a notification or the account manager tries to launch it like the following you seeing the following comments about the backstack in the log and the fragment views are null.

```
PackageManager manager = mContext.getPackageManager();
        Intent tempIntent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app");
        tempIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent = new Intent(tempIntent);
```

> 08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: moveto STARTED: AccountFragment{9913fcb #1 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: moveto RESUMED: AccountFragment{9913fcb #1 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: Commit: BackStackEntry{895f2b9}
>   08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app D/FragmentManager:   mName=null mIndex=-1 mCommitted=false
>   08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app D/FragmentManager:   Operations:
>   08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app D/FragmentManager:     Op #0: ADD AccountFragment{9913fcb #1 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app D/FragmentManager:     Op #1: ADD LocationsFragment{5455ec1 #0 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: Run: BackStackEntry{895f2b9}
>   08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: add: AccountFragment{9913fcb #1 id=0x7f0d00a1}
>   08-29 09:09:47.630 29172-29172/com.app V/FragmentManager: add: LocationsFragment{5455ec1 #0 id=0x7f0d00a1}